# Play framework production reverse routing

Tags: playframework, url-routing, playframework-2.1

I am trying to set up my Play project so that some routes that are for development purposes only do not show up in production but I am having difficulty with the reverse routing.

Here are my route files, simplified:

### routes (development)

```
GET /         controllers.Application.index()
GET /bar      controllers.Foo.bar()
```

### production.routes

```
GET /         controllers.Application.index()
```

In home.scala.html, I have something like this:

```
@if(play.Play.application().configuration().getString("application.mode") != "production") {
    <a href="@routes.Foo.bar">This link does not show up in production</a>
}
```

When running the project in production mode, the file won't compile because it can't find the route:

> value Foo is not a member of object controllers.routes

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Perhaps place that link within a sub-view (its own file), and swap out the file in production? (where the production file is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the same routes in production, the routes file is compliled, use a check in the controller if you don't want someone access at that method in your production mode.